# Securing communication between trusted servers in same hosting env

Tags: web-services, security, oauth, single-sign-on, saml

I work for a company that develops a software product that processes bank transactions and gives the user insight into his/her spending. Our customers (usually banks) integrate the product into their online banks.

I have a question about securing the communication between the online bank, and our system. Before I ask the question, I want to give you some background.

The bank will usually install our system on a set of servers in their hosting environment.

We offer a number of ways to integrate:

1. **Web services** - In this case the bank will make calls to a set of REST services on the server, and then generate a webpage with the results (on the server side).
2. **Iframes** - In this case the bank will embed iframes in their online bank webpages. The iframes contain webpages rendered directly from our web application.
3. **Inline widgets** - In this case the bank will embed JavaScript references on their pages. When the document loads, the JavaScript widgets will render themselves, using AJAX calls. They communicate with a proxy on the bank server, which in turn communicates with our webapp.

We currently have a custom solution where we generate and sign security tokens for the users, and pass these with the requests.

But as banks have very strict security policies, they would feel better with us using a known and trusted security protocol for the communication. It is a big concern, which we want to address.

So the question is, which protocol is best suited for the integration use cases I listed above? There is a plethora of single-sign-on standards out there, and solutions like SAML, oauth, etc. I get the feeling that these solutions might be an overkill for my situation.

I want to find a solution that is simple. As the servers will run side by side in the same hosting environment, and trust each other completely, there is no need for the end user to authorize one or the other (or being redirected between, clicking buttons to give access to the app).

That is, the security protocol should not require any intervention from the end user. The end user simply logs into his/her online bank, and via secure communication has access to the data from our web server.

So...any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

OGG

Answer (score 1):

After some deliberation, we decided to use 2-legged OAuth (online bank uses consumer key and consumer secret to sign requests to our app).

OAuth signature can either be put in a request header, or request parameters. It nicely solves our problem, as the REST requests can be signed, and the IFRAME src URL-s can also be signed (all communication is over HTTPS).

For those interested, a couple of references:

This article shows using OAuth with IFRAMEs: http://developer.tradeshift.com/blog/cross-site-user-verification/

This article mentiones some security issues with OAuth, and how threats can countered: http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/03/07/oauth-authorization-attacks-secure-implementation